# How to Handle Empty Response but status code 200

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I upload the file to the s3 server, and I use url.
And I'm doing networking using Alamofire.
When I uploaded the file to s3, the status code is 200, but there is no response body.

So, I can't treat Result.
error happend

> Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength

I tried but in this case it did not pass closure so, i cant treat Result..

```
.request(emptyResponseCodes:[200, 204, 205]) { response in 
    ...
}
```

```
func fetchWithEmptyResponse(target: T, completion: escaping((Int?, Error?) -> Void) {
  session.request(target)
      .responseData { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(_):
          completion(200, nil)

        case .failure(let err):
          completion(nil, err)
        }
      }

}
```

target(TargetType) T is

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public protocol TargetType: URLRequestConvertible {
  var baseURL: String { get }
  var path: String { get }
  var method: HTTPMethod { get }
  var parameters: RequestParams { get }
  var contentType: ContentType { get }
}

enum HTTPHeaderField: String {
  case authentication = "Authorization"
  case contentType = "Content-Type"
  case acceptType = "Accept"
}

public enum ContentType: String {
  case json = "Application/json"
  case image = "image/jpeg"
}

public enum RequestParams {
  case requestPlain
  case query(_ parameter: Encodable?)
  case body(_ parameter: Encodable?)
  case imageDataWithoutPath(_: Data)
}

extension TargetType {
  
  public func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    
    let url = try baseURL.asURL()

    var urlRequest = try URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path), method: method)
    urlRequest.setValue(contentType.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.contentType.rawValue)

    switch parameters {

    case .query(let request):

      let params = request?.toDictionary() ?? [:]
      let queryParams = params.map { URLQueryItem(name: $0.key, value: "\($0.value)") }
      var components = URLComponents(string: url.appendingPathComponent(path).absoluteString)
      
      components?.queryItems = queryParams
      urlRequest.url = components?.url

    case .body(let request):
      let params = request?.toDictionary() ?? [:]
      urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])

    case .imageDataWithoutPath(let data):

      let reURL = try baseURL.asURL()
      urlRequest.url = reURL
      urlRequest.httpBody = data

    case .requestPlain:
      break
    }

    return urlRequest
  }
}
```

So My Question is

How can I treat Empty Response?

- if status code 200, and Empty Response, i wanna handle it and then using @escpaing completionHandler i wanna pass value.

Sorry for my poor English. And Thank you for read

Comment: An empty response body is not a valid JSON. Any attempt to decode an empty array of UTF-8 to a JSON representation (aka struct or class) will fail. It's a frequent use case when the response body sometimes is JSON, sometimes text/html, etc., depending on the status code. This can be solved very easily with some sort of API layer on top of URLSession. I don't know if Alamofire supports this use case, if not, I would recommend to try to implement your API without Alamofire first.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thank you for your answer.
Actually,  Alamofire supported this case. i just took mistake..

What I wrote above was the answer.
When I looked closely, I went through the closure.
`
.request(emptyResponseCodes:[200, 204, 205]) { response in 
    ...
}
`

it seems to manipulate possible too.
[link](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3088)
[link](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2466)

Answer (score 0):

Check inside of parameter key count == 0 or key == nil

example:

```
   {
     "status" : "success",
     "data" : []
   }
```

now I checked

```
 if status == "success"{
       if data.count > 0{
         print(data[0])
       }
       else{
         print("Data Empty")
       }
  }
```

Comment: s3 dont give any data..   literally no response body